# Comparing set sizes of algorithms that explain strings from a blackbox algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, convergence

Let's say that I have a blackbox algorithm that takes no parameters, does not halt, and produces values at some rate.  Now then, let's say that over 10000 values, the string always follows symbol 'A' with symbol 'B', and it has done this 100 times.

What this proves is only that the algorithm is one which behaved according to records, and did not behave otherwise.  We can argue that the relationship between 'A' and 'B' is more likely to persist throughout the algorithm every time we experience this relationship. We can say this because the ratio:

((algorithms that could have this happen by chance + algorithms that had this happen as result of a state that is no longer active/will not remain active)/rulesets where a ruleset that explains the relationship remains active)

needs to approach 0 as the string length approaches infinity, and by definition that is true (I think)!

But the string never reaches infinity, and it would be nice to be able to figure out what the curve related to this ratio should actually look like, but I have no idea where to start.  Does anyone out there have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think the following is true:

> What this proves is only that the algorithm is one which behaved
>   according to records, and did not behave otherwise.

But not this:

> We can argue that the relationship between 'A' and 'B' is more likely
>   to persist throughout the algorithm every time we experience this
>   relationship.

How could we know that the program won't do something else in the future? For example, consider the set of data-generating programs that look like this:

```
repeat n times:
    print("A")
    print("B")

do something else
```

$n$ can take any natural number, so there's an infinite number of these programs. After observing a finite number of timesteps $t < n$, the output is indistinguishable from programs where the relationship between symbols A and B is maintained indefinitely. E.g. something like this:

```
while True:
    print("A")
    print("B")
```

All of these programs are deterministic, so for all them, the likelihood of "ABABAB..." (for however many timesteps we've observed) is 1.

To get out of this quandary, we'd need to impose additional constraints. For example, we could declare that we have higher prior belief in short programs (quantified as the program length in bits). This is the approach taken in [Solomonoff induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomonoff_induction). Another topic of interest is [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity). Note that these are both theoretical, not practical tools.

As a side point (technical detail), if the data generating process doesn't halt, it can't really be called an algorithm (which halts by definition).

Comment: I'm attempting to read the wiki on solomonoff's induction, although i'm not familiar with a lot of the language.  I think this is exactly what i was looking for, thank you!  Would this be a theory i could ask questions about here and expect responses too?

Comment: @Battlefrisk Possibly. It does involve learning and a Bayesian formulation. Then again, also things like Turing machines. You could try here and computer science stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Could you approach this question with Bayes' rule?

It appears to me that the ratio you are looking for is $1 - p(B|A)$.

When you start your algorithm, the initial results will appear to be some random sequence. Your prior probability for observing any $Y$ after having first observed $X$ would be 0, but you would update the prior as you begin to observe $Y$ following $X$ with some frequency. In other words, if your algorithm begins to produce a seemingly non-random sequence of cases where 'B' follows 'A' then you would want to look at the proportion of times that this sequence has already occurred in your algorithm's history in estimating the ratio you seek.

Your question concerns the probability of observing 'B' given that the algorithm just produced an 'A': $p(B|A)$. According to Bayes' rule the solution to that conditional probability is:

$$
p(B|A) = \frac{p(B) \times p(A|B)}{p(A)}
$$

(Note that this formulation has the symbols reversed from how it is typically presented in order to match the problem posed in the question.)

$p(B)$ would be the total number of times you witnessed the string 'B' *including but not limited to the cases where 'A' preceded 'B'*, divided by length of the string. $p(A|B)$ would be the percentage of times you have already witnessed the 'A' followed by 'B' string, divided by length of the string. And $p(A)$ would be the proportion of all observations of 'A', *again including but not limited to the cases where 'A' was followed by 'B'*.

Your interest, therefore is in monitoring and/or plotting the evolution of the probability $[1 - p(B|A)]$. As the prior probability of observing a 'B' following 'A' increases with additional observations, the probability that the algorithm continues to produce this pattern by chance would decline toward zero.

Comment: It seems that base's rule is working off the assumption that what happened in the past is evidence of the rules in play currently, but that's just not the case is it?  The algorithm running in the blackbox could be any algorithm that would produce the results seen thus far, including the many that would stop producing the perceived pattern.

Comment: I see what you're saying. If there are infinite possible algorithms, and you do not know which one is generating the answer updating to the string at any given moment, then it seems like you cannot say anything about the probability of the pattern happening by anything other than chance.

Comment: The P(A|B), etc. description seems to be considering only the set of first order Markov chains